# How do I handle "warning: use of ‘auto’ in parameter declaration only available with -fconcepts"

Tags: c++, warnings, c++-concepts

This is the code that cause the warning:

```
inline auto getclock() { return std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
inline auto getelapsed(auto b, auto e) { return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(e-b).count(); }
//USAGE: auto b=getclock(); some_func_to_be_timed(...); auto duration=getelapsed(b, getclock()); ..
```

This code compiled without problem  before I recently upgraded to gcc 8 (c++17), now I get the warning as stated in the question.
Why would I get this warning now, and how should I handle it?

PS: I don't use concepts (explicitly) anywhere in the rest of the code.

Comment: The compiler suggests you to add `-fconcepts` as a compiler option. Try that! Also did you *explicitly* pass `-std=c++17` to it?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I know that. Did not need the flag before, why now? What is the effect of the flag; I do not have access to the C++ standards papers, and want to know if maybe to explicitly replace auto with the actual types should be the better solution?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: yes std=c++17 is passed explicitly. Are there hidden consequences to doing that?

Comment: It is only a *warning*

Answer (score 11):

`auto` as parameter are not allowed for regular functions in C++17.
(It is in C++20).

You might use regular template, something like:

```
template <typename T> // or T1, T2 to mimic your code
auto getelapsed(T b, T e)
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(e-b).count();
}
```

Comment: (Hi!) I'll do that to kill the warning. It' strange that there were no complaints when using -std=c++14 (also explicitly passed), and now there is.

Comment: Probably an gcc extension and/or incoming (C++20) concept implementation.

Comment: I was using -std=c++17 on g++ 7.3 and also had no warning. I find that typically newer compilers are more stringently compliant, and that it wasn't a warning before is probably an error. Eventually it will be part of the language, but not yet.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usage, to avoid the warning in C++17, you can **turn the function into a lambda**.  Example below.

This function gives compiler warning:

```
void show(auto... param) {
  std::printf(param...);
}
```

This lambda does not:

```
auto show = [] (auto... param) -> void {
  std::printf(param...);
};
```